# Call a function after a Thread is completed

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sftp, jprogressbar

i'm writing a Sftp-client program using Jsch. I am using JProgressBars to display the Progress of Uploads and Downloads. My GUI contains Buttons according to the files in my Working Directory. When i delete a file i updated my gui to give the user a feedback:

```
void update() {
    panel.removeAll();
    addToPanel(ls(channelsftp, sftpWorkingDir));
    validate();
}
```

This is using my ls-function to return all Files in the current workingDir. addToPanel will process the lsEntries to output Buttons on the panel. This works great for deleting files. However, i want the same update-function to be called after an upload is completed. Since upload is giving me graphical feedback in the form of a JProgressBar its functionality was moved to a thread:

```
final JFileChooser uploadChooser = new JFileChooser();
    ulo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int returnVal = uploadChooser.showOpenDialog(Navigator.this);
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                String pathToUpload = uploadChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                Runnable uploadIt = new UploadUtil(pathToUpload, chacha);
                new Thread(uploadIt).start();
            }   
        }
    });
```

So after the user clicks on OK in this JFileChooser the upload starts. Here is UploadUtil:

```
public class UploadUtil implements Runnable{

    String paTU;
    ChannelSftp csftp;

    public UploadUtil(String pathToUl, ChannelSftp chaSftp) {
        paTU = pathToUl;
        csftp = chaSftp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            csftp.put(paTU, LoginAndFunctions.sftpWorkingDir, new SystemOutProgressMonitor());
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            Error errorUploading = new Error(e.toString()+"\nUploadpipe closed unexpectedly");
            errorUploading.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

SystemOutProgressMonitor is a class that processes datatransfer in Jsch.
I tried using Thread.join() and CountDownLatch. Both prevented my JProgressBar from updating. Is there a different solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use a call back method or mechanism. Since this is a Swing problem, use a SwingWorker, not a Runnable in a thread which gives you **two** potential ways

- The `done()` method is called within the worker **on the Swing event thread** when it has completed its job.
- Or add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker, listen to the "state" property, and react when the new value is `SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE`.

Note that you can also add a PropertyChangeListener to the worker thread and listen to its progress property. Within the worker as it's updating your data, update this property by calling `setProgress(int value)` with a value from 0 to 100. Then in the listener, update your JProgressBar with this value.

For example (Note that code not tested yet, so sorry if there are errors):

```
public class UploadUtil extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    String paTU;
    ChannelSftp csftp;

    public UploadUtil(String pathToUl, ChannelSftp chaSftp) {
        paTU = pathToUl;
        csftp = chaSftp;
    }

    @Override
    public void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try {
            csftp.put(paTU, LoginAndFunctions.sftpWorkingDir, new SystemOutProgressMonitor());
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            Error errorUploading = new Error(e.toString()+"\nUploadpipe closed unexpectedly");
            errorUploading.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

A listener for your worker:

```
class UploadUtilListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    public void propertyChanged(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        if (e.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
            // do your code here that you want called when worker done
        }
    }
}
```

then to use it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int returnVal = uploadChooser.showOpenDialog(Navigator.this);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String pathToUpload = uploadChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        UploadUtil uploadIt = new UploadUtil(pathToUpload, chacha);
        uploadIt.addPropertyChangeListener(new UploadUtilListener());
        uploadIt.execute();
    }   
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Actually SystemOutProgressMonitor already has an end() function, that is called once the Process is completed. I could call update there, but update needs to be static for this. It cant be static, since i'm calling validate there. validate() will be called on the Navigator class, which extends JFrame. Am i missing something?

Comment: @RonnyBrandt: then your problem is not as you fully describe it in your question, since this **does** show a valid solution of how to call Swing code on the Swing event thread, when a background thread has completed. If this doesn't work, then you need to update your question, mainly by creating and posting a valid [mcve]. For your MCVE, use `Thread.sleep` to simulate the long-running background process, as this will allow us to run your code without files and dependencies that we don't have.

Comment: Yea, it is working now. My solution was to call UploadUtil with Navigator.this to work around the static/non-static issue... Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @RonnyBrandt: I'm glad that you've got things fixed. I have to comment that there shouldn't be a static/non-static issue though. Everything but the main method, and perhaps some singletons, should be run in the instance (non-static) world. If you're having an issue with this, it suggests that your code might benefit from a re-design. Good luck!

Comment: Everything does run in the 'instance' world. My main method only creates an Object of another class, its only 2 lines of code there. But i created an object of UploadUtil. UploadUtil cant call validate() on Navigator. But i can pass my Navigator Object through when i instanciate UploadUtil. Should i redesign this?

Comment: I'm guessing it's OK (without seeing code, hard to tell), if you're not having to make fields static to achieve this.